# Django passing a list of tuples in a form and getting it in the view

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-views, django-templates

I have a list of tuples in this format: [(a,b,c), (d,e,f),(g,h,i)]. For some reasons, I need to pass it as a hidden field in my form and in my views I need to retrieve it. However, Im not able to do it.

Here is my code snippet:

html template

```
<form id="form1" action="{% url 'job_recommendations' %}" method="POST">
   {% csrf_token %}
   <a onclick="document.getElementById('form1').submit();">View more recommendations&nbsp</a
   <input type="hidden" name="recommendations" value="{{ job_recommendations }}"> #it 
    is the list that I want to pass. It already has correct values
</form>
```

views.py

```
def job_recommendations(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        recommendations = request.POST['recommendations']

        for job, recruiter, percentage in recommendations:
            print(percentage) 

return render(request, 'recommendations.html')
```

Comment: Do you really need to do this that way? I'm not sure about jinja formating tuple in templates, but you'd probably get string and not list at this point `for job, recruiter, percentage in recommendations:`. You can format this tuple as json and then pass it to template.

Comment: @kacpo1, yes.. u mean in the views?

Comment: @kacpo1, i get this error when trying to unpack in views ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 3, got 1)

Comment: Yes, because what you have in your template is `[(a,b,c), (d,e,f),(g,h,i)]` but type string. So its literaly string representation of list.

Answer (score 0):

It's not the best way to do this, but you can use `ast` module.
Jinja would put `[(a,b,c), (d,e,f),(g,h,i)]` as string in template. You would get this string in your view, then you can call `ast.literal_eval(str)` function on this string to convert this string into list.

Please remember that this is very unsecure because it allows user from frontend to execute code on backend.

Comment: do I need to import it?

Comment: It's build-in module so you don't need to download it, but yes you need to import it like every other module.

Comment: i dont find the  proper  statement for importing ast for django

Comment: It's python build-in module, not django. Just use `import ast`.

Comment: with this  recommendations_list = ast.literal_eval(recommendations), im getting invalid syntax :/

Comment: `Invalid syntax` error means that you did something wrong in your python code, it's not fault of `ast`. Please post your new code.